# Inspect class object of mocked method

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I am writing a test of a function which sends a pandas dataframe to a sql database using the dataframe's `to_sql()` method.

To avoid actually sending anything, I am mocking the method using `mock.patch('pandas.DataFrame.to_sql')`.

I would like to see the state of the dataframe at the time of calling `to_sql()`. Is there any way to do this using the mock? I.e., is it aware of the object from which the mocked function was called?

The function I am testing is not currently returning anything. Would that be necessary to check the dataframe? E.g. returning the dataframe after the `to_sql()` call? I don't need the return value for anything other than making this test, so would prefer another way if possible.

Comment: Hi @Kaspar! I am facing exactly the same issue as you did back then right now and I have not found any way to get the dataframe from mocking the connection.

Where you able to troubleshoot around this? Or you just simply updated the function to return the dataframe?

Comment: Hi @LetsiosMatthaios, sorry I actually can't remember. If I had to start over today, I'd look into side effects, but not sure if they can accomplish what I originally asked for.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up refactoring the code by setting up a function to return the dataframe just before storing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution is this:

```
@mock.patch('pandas.DataFrame.to_sql', return_value=mock.MagicMock())
def test_method(self: my_to_sql_mock):
  #your code...
```

I hope this works for you